# Persist nifi data and volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I want to make my `nifi` data volume and configuration persist means even if I delete container and `docker compose up` again I would like to keep what I built so far in my `nifi`. I try to mount volumes as follows in my docker compose file in volumes section nevertheless it doesn't work and my nifi processors are not saved. How can I do it correctly? Below my `docker-compose.yaml` file.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nifi:
    image: koroslak/nifi:latest
    container_name: nifi
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NIFI_HOME=/opt/nifi/nifi-current
      - NIFI_LOG_DIR=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
      - NIFI_PID_DIR=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/run
      - NIFI_BASE_DIR=/opt/nifi
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    depends_on:
      - openldap
    volumes:
      - ./volume/nifi-current/state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
      - ./volume/database/database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/repositories/database_repository
      - ./volume/flow_storage/flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/repositories/flowfile_repository
      - ./volume/nifi-current/content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/repositories/content_repository
      - ./volume/nifi-current/provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/repositories/provenance_repository
      - ./volume/log:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
      #- ./volume/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf

  postgres:
    image: koroslak/postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret123
    ports:
      - 6000:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - 8090:80

  metabase:
    container_name: metabase
    image: metabase/metabase:v0.34.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      MB_DB_TYPE: postgres
      MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase
      MB_DB_PORT: 5432
      MB_DB_USER: metabase_admin
      MB_DB_PASS: secret123
      MB_DB_HOST: postgres
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  openldap:
    image: osixia/openldap:1.3.0
    container_name: openldap
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 38999:389

# Mocked source systems
  jira-api:
    image: danielgtaylor/apisprout:latest
    container_name: jira-api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mvrabel/nifi-postgres-metabase/master/api_examples/jira-api.json

  pipedrive-api:
    image: danielgtaylor/apisprout:latest
    container_name: pipedrive-api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8100:8000
    command: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mvrabel/nifi-postgres-metabase/master/api_examples/pipedrive-api.yaml

  restcountries-api:
    image: danielgtaylor/apisprout:latest
    container_name: restcountries-api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8200:8000
    command: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mvrabel/nifi-postgres-metabase/master/api_examples/restcountries-api.json

volumes:
  postgres:
  nifi:
  openldap:
  metabase:
  pgadmin:
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html) you can achieve that all changes you are doing or your nifi are committed to git. I.e. if you change some processor configuration, it will be reflected in your git repo.
As for flow files, you may need to fix volumes mappings.

Comment: Can u provide how then my file could Look like including that registry please

Comment: What file? I haven't understand this question.

Comment: The yaml file..

Comment: NiFi registry is used mainly for Versioning your workflow. Not the data behind. You can versioning on local, db, or github (1 way sync).